# React not re-rendering after state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I'm currently learning React. In my homepage component, I'm using a hook to initialize and populate the state. I have 2 states, 1 contains a random pokemon and another is an array of 20 random pokemons. The first one works fine, but not the array.

Here's the homepage component:

```
// Hook
import { useHomeFetch } from "../hooks/useHomeFetch";
// Image
import NoImage from '../images/missingno.png';

const Home = () => {
    const { state, collection, loading, error } = useHomeFetch();
    return (
        <>
            { state.heroPokemon ?
            <HeroImage 
                image={`${API.fetchSprite(state.heroPokemon)}`}
                title={state.heroPokemon.name}
                text='Placeholder, should include abilities, etc. to show the pokemon off.'
            />
            : null}
            { collection.pokemons[0] ?
            <Grid header='Popular pokemons'>
                {collection.pokemons.map( pokemon => (
                    <h3 key={pokemon.id}>{pokemon.name}</h3>
                ) )}
            </Grid>
            : null}
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

The heroPokemon works fine after I added the conditional rendering. My first thought was to do the same thing with the collection, as it might have rendered before all of the API call promises have resolved.

If I look at the react dev tools, this is what I see for the state:

```
hooks
HomeFetch

1 State : {heroPokemon: {…}}
2 State : {pokemons: Array(20)}
           pokemons :
               [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
```

So it looks to me that the call indeed completed fine with 20 random pokemon objects in there.

Here's is the hook:

```
const initialState = {
    heroPokemon: null
}

const fetchRandomPokemons = async (ids) => {
    let pokemons = [];
    ids.forEach(async num => {
        pokemons.push(await API.fetchPokemon(num));
    });
    return pokemons;
}

export const useHomeFetch = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
    const [collection, setCollection] = useState({pokemons: []});
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    
    const fetchPokemons = async (limit = 20) => {
        try {
            setError(false);
            setLoading(true);
            
            const heroPokemon = await API.fetchPokemon(randomInt(1, 898));
            const randomInts = randomUniqueInt(1, 898, limit);
            const pokemons = await fetchRandomPokemons(randomInts);

            setState(prev => ({heroPokemon}));
            setCollection(prev => ({pokemons}));
        } catch (error) {
            setError(true);
        }
        setLoading(false);
        
    };
    // Initial render
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPokemons(20);
    }, [])

    return { state, collection, loading, error };
};
```

When I take out the conditional, `Grid` shows up, but it doesn't have the h3s with the pokemon names in them. If I console.log out `state` and `collection` right before the return in `home`. The last few ones show the correct `state.heroPokemon` and `collection.pokemons` populated correctly. This leads me to believe that the states are updated correctly, but why is React not re-rendering the grid component?

To add, I also tried adding this:

```
<p>{collection.pokemons[0]}</p>
```

To the home component, and nothing shows up. I feel like I may be misunderstanding or missing a crucial part of how states and re-renders work, which is leading me to missing what I could be doing wrong.

EDIT:
Here's what the API call returns: pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto
I also debugged `Home` and this is what it looks like: imgur.com/a/jVhaSsk

I'm confused now because `pokemon.name` clearly exists and is not undefined. Why are they not populating in the `h3`s?

EDIT 2:
I changed the home component to this:

```
<Grid header='Popular pokemons'>
{
    state.results.map(pokemon => {
        console.log(pokemon.name)
        return <h3>pokemon name</h3>
     })
}
</Grid>
```

And it looks like the `h3`s are still empty. Is it still waiting for the promises in the array? But the `console.log`s are printing out the pokemon names fine.

EDIT 3:
Thanks to Drew, I found where the problem lies.
This is what my `Grid` component looks like:

```
import React from "react";

import { Wrapper, Content } from './Grid.styles';

const Grid = ({ header }) => (
    <Wrapper>
        <h1>{header}</h1>
    </Wrapper>
);

export default Grid;
```

I'm using `styled-components` as well, and here's the file:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
    max-width: var(--maxWidth);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;

    h1 {
        color: var(--medGrey);

        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            font-size: var(--fontBig);
        }
    }
`;

export const Content = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 2rem;
`;
```

As you can see, `Content` isn't in `Wrapper`. After I changed it to:

```
const Grid = ({ header, children }) => (
    <Wrapper>
        <h1>{header}</h1>
        <Content>{children}</Content>
    </Wrapper>
);
```

It worked perfectly. It looks like the array of Pokemons are being passed to `Grid` as `{children}`, so when it doesn't exist well it doesn't render it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

It seems the issue is in your `fetchRandomPokemons` utility function. Even though you've declared `fetchRandomPokemons` `async` you are not waiting for anything. `Array.prototype.forEach` is also completely synchronous as well. You *did however* declare the `.forEach` callback to `async` and `await` the API response, but because `.forEach` is synchronous the `fetchRandomPokemons` function has already returned the empty `pokemons` array and resolved. The `async` keyword only allows a function scope to use the `await` keyword.

```
const fetchRandomPokemons = async (ids) => {
  let pokemons = [];
  ids.forEach(async num => { // <-- synchronous
    pokemons.push(await API.fetchPokemon(num));
  });
  return pokemons; // <-- returns []
}

...

const pokemons = await fetchRandomPokemons(randomInts); // <-- []

setCollection({ pokemons }); // <-- { pokemons: [] }
```

What you are logging is the `pokemons` array that the `.forEach` array mutated when each `API.fetchPokemon` Promise resolved.

## Solution

Map the `ids` to an array of Promises and wait them all to resolve and return the resolved array of pokemons.

```
const fetchRandomPokemons = (ids) => {
  return Promise.all(ids.map(API.fetchPokemon));
}
```

...

```
const fetchPokemons = async (limit = 20) => {
  setError(false);
  setLoading(true);

  try {
    const heroPokemon = await API.fetchPokemon(randomInt(1, 898));
    const randomInts = randomUniqueInt(1, 898, limit);
    const pokemons = await fetchRandomPokemons(randomInts);

    setState({ heroPokemon });
    setCollection({ pokemons });
  } catch (error) {
    setError(true);
  }
  setLoading(false);
};
```

### Update

Adding running codesandbox and screencap.

[image: Edit react-not-re-rendering-after-state-update]

[image]

Comment: Hello Drew, thanks for the explanation. This got the ```h3```s to show, but they're empty. Am I displaying them wrong in the ```Home``` component?

Also, a question on how React works. In my original solution, it would've filled the array with unresolved promises before the component renders. But as they resolve, shouldn't react detect that and re-render?

Thanks!

Comment: @Lavzh If the `h3` elements are rendering but empty then I suppose that `pokemon.name` is undefined. Can you update your question to include what the `collection.pokemons` value is that you are mapping? Regarding the other question, no, React won't do anything above/beyond checking that state is a new object reference to trigger any rerenders. It just sees the array change from `[]` to one with a bunch of objects (*Promise objects*) in them.

Comment: Here's an API call response example: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto. the object is the same as the heroPokemon. 20 h3s are showing up, so clearly the object is in there.

I also debugged it and this is what it looks like, name should be defined:
https://imgur.com/a/jVhaSsk

Comment: @Lavzh The code appears to work without issue for me in the codesandbox linked in my updated answer. Please do check it out.

Comment: Thank you so much, that led me into figuring out what was wrong. Last question before I accept your solution, I've updated the question with the details on what I did. When I pass the pokemon names like this:
```
<Grid header='Popular pokemons'>
{
    state.results.map(pokemon => {
        console.log(pokemon.name)
        return <h3>pokemon name</h3>
     })
}
</Grid>
``` in the home component. Does it implicitly get passed as a component children? Because I thought I'd have to pass it as a prop as it's a parameter in the ```Grid``` component.

Comment: @Lavzh Yes, everything between `<Grid>` and `</Grid>` is passed on the `children` prop by React. ***Now***, whether or not the `Grid` component uses the `children` prop is an implementation detail of `Grid`.

Comment: @Lavzh And oh, lol, yeah, just went back to read your edits... and see that `Grid` is a component of yours and that you weren't destructuring the `children` prop and rendering it.

Comment: Thank you! Your answers were really thorough and gave me a better understanding on how React components and asynchronous JS work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 // Hook
import { useHomeFetch } from "../hooks/useHomeFetch";
// Image
import NoImage from '../images/missingno.png';

const Home = () => {
    const [newCollection, setNewCollection] =useState([])
    const { state, collection, loading, error } = useHomeFetch();
    
    useEffect(()=>{
       setNewCollection(collection || []);
     },[collection])

 
    return (
        <>
            { state.heroPokemon ?
            <HeroImage 
                image={`${API.fetchSprite(state.heroPokemon)}`}
                title={state.heroPokemon.name}
                text='Placeholder, should include abilities, etc. to show the pokemon off.'
            />
            : null}
            { newCollection.pokemons[0] ?
            <Grid header='Popular pokemons'>
                {newCollection.pokemons.map( pokemon => (
                    <h3 key={pokemon.id}>{pokemon.name}</h3>
                ) )}
            </Grid>
            : null}
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

if still not work than share your repo. so I can help you more. Thanks